# What are the variables that determine the number of nodes required in Hyperledger Indy Setup?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-indy

As part of one of my project implementation, I have to use Hyperledger Indy for providing digital identity to users. The estimated number of users on the platform is 20k. I am stuck on determining what must be the number of nodes required to run Hyperledger Indy for efficient use on production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of nodes depends on the number of faulty nodes you want to permit. To support f faults in the system, you need 3f+1 total nodes. So if you are OK with only 2 nodes failing at any one time, you need f=2 or 7 total nodes. The practical limit has found to be f=8 or 25 total nodes. That balances a robust network with the speed of consensus.

How that relates to the number of users on the platform is a different question. It depends on (a) how many issuers, and (b) how much revocation is happening.
If there is only one issuer and no revocation, there would only be 3 extra transactions beyond the genesis transactions. Not many...